# How to transition element into a style and then back on hover?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I want the div to transition into its `:hover` style and then back, on hover, and on out of hover. I know I can use animations but I don't know how to implement it to this scenario.

I want it to transform like so (on hover and also on unhover):

- From: `transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg)`.
- To: `transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(30deg)`.
- Then back to: `transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg)`.

```css
#lorem {
  width: 250px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  transition: transform .75s ease-in-out;
  }
#lorem:hover {
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(30deg);
  }
```

```html
<div id="lorem">LOREM</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using two animations. The key was to make the animations have different values, as they would not be triggered if they were exactly the same, even with a different animation name. So you could change `1deg` in the `rotateX(0deg)` through the two animations to trigger the change

```css
@keyframes fold {
    0%   {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);}
    50%  {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(30deg);}
    100% {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);}
}

@keyframes unfold {
    0%   {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);}
    50%  {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(15deg);}
    100% {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);}
}
#lorem {
  width: 250px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  transition: transform .75s ease-in-out;
  animation: fold .75s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal;
  }
#lorem:hover {
  animation: unfold .75s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal;
  }
```

```html
<div id="lorem">LOREM</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're super close to getting there yourself! Just remember that whenever you want to transition from one state to another, you need to define an initial state. So in the original `#lorem` state, add the initial `transform` property and it should work fine. The only line added is the `transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);`. See the below snippet:

```css
#lorem {
  width: 250px;
  height: 18px;
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform .75s ease-in-out;
}

#lorem:hover {
  transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="lorem">LOREM</div>
```

Comment: Idk how to explain this better. I want it to go from `rotateX(0deg)` to `rotateX(30deg)` to `rotateX(0deg)` on hover. When you unhover, the same would happen.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry for the misunderstanding. That makes more sense. You'll use the animation property then. Joshua Rajandiran's answer is getting closer than mine currently, though I'll edit mine to get closer to the target.

Comment: Sorry I didn't word my question better. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the answer given by ghost_dad. If you wanted the div to change to its hover state, then maybe you can try using an animation like this instead:

```css
#lorem {
    width: 250px;
    height: 18px;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 12px;
    animation-name : example;
    animation-duration: .75s;
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    transition: transform .75s ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#lorem:hover {
    transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(30deg);
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);}
    to {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(30deg);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    from {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);}
    to {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(30deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="lorem">LOREM</div>
```

If you wanted it to stay rotated then you can do something like this:

```css
#lorem {
    width: 250px;
    height: 18px;
    background: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 12px;
    animation-name : example;
    animation-duration: .75s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(30deg);
    transition: transform .75s ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#lorem:hover {
    transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);}
    to {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(30deg);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    from {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(0deg);}
    to {transform: perspective(320px) rotateX(30deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="lorem">LOREM</div>
```